# jenkins html reports link : can't index the index.html file automatically

Tags: plugins, jenkins

This is the URL without [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0RPW.png) at the end( it doesn't work)

And this is the one I manually add [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi4MK.png) to the end(it works)

ps:Ubuntu Server 14.04.2/Jenkins 1.641

Comment: tttlh please be specific with your question

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @tttlh?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same bugs.

Update your Jenkins and the Html Report Plugin. This will solve your problem

Comment: Alas this did not solve my problem